position of images with css
okay, im doing one of my first pages with html and css, and look, you know that operagx and the other browser have the normal size screen and the fullscreen when you press f11, the problem here is that my page in the normal size of the browser is in a position, and when i fullscreen obviously it expands, but when it expands, an image that i have on the page is hiding behinf another img, because it is going a little bit to the left, is there some way to fix that? like, to fix the image in one point and it doesnt change?
the purpose is that: there is a girl and on the head of this girl, there are 3 butterflies surrounding her, one on the top, one on the left and one on the right of the head, in the normal size screen she is in the middle of this three butterflies, but when i fullscreen, the butterflies move to the left a little bit and hide behind the girl.
i tried adjusting a lot of width,margin,position and nothing is changing, always that image is hiding, you know?

A purely verbal description isn't debuggable. Please provide enough code so we can help you - without it any answer is just a guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Setting the display property of the images to fixed will ensure that the images always stay in the same place.
selector {
    position: fixed;
}

